# blueprintjs/datetime pick different date/time when select using mouse click and input using keyboard

Tags: reactjs, date, datetime, internationalization, blueprintjs

I need to pick a date from blueprintjs using [datetimePicker](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#datetime/dateinput). The point is that when I select any day (for example 2017-11-11):

1. Using **mouse click** a get resulting time 12:00 am. and this component looks at my timezone (+2) and takes this into acount. As a result I got date --> 2017-11-11 10:00.
2. Using **keyboard** time is 00.00. I got date --> 2017-11-10 22:00. this is the previous day.

if it is a bag maybe there is a scenarious where I can skip timezones. Because I do not need time... Only date.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need time then use `DatePicker`.